# Как получить фотографии здания используя API Яндекс.Карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-places-api

Необходимо получить фотографии здания с Яндекс.Карт. Как это можно сделать посредством API?

Comment: API Карт не даёт доступа к фотографиям зданий и организаций

Answer (score 0):

Как написала Reni, получить пользовательские фотографии зданий по API нельзя. Возможно, вам подойдет такой вариант: если нужное вам здание попадает на панораму Яндекса, вы можете загрузить её через [плеер панорам](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/panoramas/yandex-panoramas.html) и установить [направление взгляда по умолчанию](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/panorama.Player.html#panorama.Player__param-options.direction) на этом здании ([пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/panorama_basics)).